# How to index the first element of a list, and apply it to each row of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a column of list objects which contains elements of Dates, I want to select the first date and mutate as a new column, but now I have some indexing problems.

I have tried indexing the list, but it don't work for each rows, but always shows the first element of the first row.
The code shows below:

```r
> head(data$Date)
[[1]]
 [1] "2016-06-08" "2016-06-08" "2016-06-13" "2016-06-13" "2016-06-13" "2016-06-14"
 [7] "2016-06-14" "2016-06-14" "2016-06-14" "2016-06-14" "2016-06-14" "2016-09-15"
[13] "2016-10-31"

[[2]]
[1] "2016-10-02"

[[3]]
[1] "2016-09-25"

[[4]]
[1] "2017-02-16"

> data %>%
+     mutate(time1 = Date[[1]][1])%>%
+     select(time1)
# A tibble: 29,036 x 1
   time1     
   <chr>     
 1 2016-06-08
 2 2016-06-08
 3 2016-06-08
 4 2016-06-08
 5 2016-06-08
 6 2016-06-08
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can also use `pluck` with `reduce` that make sure the `Date`s are not coerced to `numeric`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    mutate(time1 =  map(Date, pluck, 1) %>%
                       reduce(c))
```

If we need the `last`, `pluck` the `last`

```
data %>%
   mutate(time1 = map(Date, pluck, last) %>% 
                    reduce(c))
```

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of c?

Comment: @Bathe `c` stands for concatenation.  It will place two elements, vectors, lists join together to create a single vector/list etc.  You can check `c(1, 2)`

Comment: @Bathe I updated with an option to extract the last element

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.By the way, could you recommend materials to learn purrr package?

Comment: @Bathe You could check the vignettes and other materials from [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

`unnest_wider()` from *tidyr* worked for me well

```
data %>%
tidyr::unnest_wider(col = Date ) %>% 
  select(1, Date = 2)
```

For each element of the list (new row added for 2nd and following element) just use `unnest()`

```
data %>%
tidyr::unnest(cols = Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `map` function from the tidyverse package `purrr`:

```
data %>%
  mutate(time1 = map(Date, ~ .[[1]]) %>% unlist()) %>% 
  select(time1)
```

The `map()` function will extract the first element of each list element. As `map` returns a list by default, you need to `unlist()` the output to put it in a column the way you want to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, then how to extract the last element? R seems not provide index like [-1] to refer to the last one.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that only uses dplyr is to just use the `rowwise()` function, which applies functions within mutate separately in each row.

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(petals = list(Petal.Length)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(first = first(petals), last = last(petals))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   Species    petals     first  last
#>   <fct>      <list>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 setosa     <dbl [50]>   1.4   1.4
#> 2 versicolor <dbl [50]>   4.7   4.1
#> 3 virginica  <dbl [50]>   6     5.1
```